# word for 'someone who came back from the dead'

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a cool name that is similar in meaning to 'someone who came back from the dead'. if it's feminine that will be great. I have a laptop that was dead for a long time and I have got it working again. I am thinking to give it a cool name.

Comment: To come back from the dead is to have been resurrected

Comment: yes, but is there a name that come close to this meaning, any language

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resurrection_Mary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to consider "**[Eurydice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eurydice)**, "[**Inanna**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inanna)," and "[**Ishtar**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ishtar)."

Comment: Not sure whether Orpheus was sucessful, though :)

Comment: But Eurydice did *not* return from the dead.

Comment: @StoneyB Well, I guess it was a near miss for her. :-)

Comment: Not her fault, though; it was a clear case of operator error.

Answer (score 4):

Revenant; a person who has returned, especially supposedly from the dead.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a female name but Lazarus is the one that comes to mind.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazarus_of_Bethany

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you want to use it for. My first thought was Lazarus, as Rueh mentioned, but Phoenix possibly sounds a little more feminine? Not sure whether it technically rises from the dead, but certainly from the ashes.

Answer (score 0):

While not quite a name, peraps **[The Bride of Frankenstein](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0026138/)**.

(The Bride does not seem to have a given name, but Elsa Lanchester who plays her also plays Mary Wollstonecraft Shelly. Hey, maybe *Wollstonecraft*?)